# How can I change the setting on a Mac computer where out-of-focus windows are greyed out?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

When a window is not active, its interface turns grey. If I connect multiple screens and click on one of them, the menu bars on the other screens also turn grey. This setting is quite inconvenient. Is there a way to disable this setting?

Comment: Can you explain more about the inconvenience of grey menu bars on displays that don't have the current focus? You can still move the pointer and click on a grey menu to display its contents.

Comment: Would the same designers of Mac think that windows losing focus without turning grey would be harmful? In fact, this logic of turning grey when out of focus requires extra effort to implement. Personally, I set my screen brightness very low, and if it turns grey, I can't see the text and buttons clearly. Please don't question why I lower my screen brightness. I hope we can return to the issue at hand.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to change this behaviour, no. You could maybe change the contrast and accessibility options to improve the visibility at low brightness.